# How to write a cleaner code for this piece of php snippet?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know if there is a better/shorter/cleaner/resource saving method for this snippet of php code with codeigniter? Thanks.

```
$code = $this->uri->segment(3);

if (!$code) {
    // validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'PassCode', 'required|trim|max_length[100]|xss_clean');

    // run validation to check if validation rules are satifised
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $user_id = $this->user_model->getUserId($code);
        if (empty($user_id)) {
            $data['errorMessage'] = 'Your code is not valid.';
        } else {
            redirect('user/profile');   
        }
    }
} else {
    $user_id = $this->user_model->getUserId($code);
    if (empty($user_id)) {
        $data['errorMessage'] = 'Your code is not valid.';
    } else {
        redirect('user/profile');   
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the codeigniter style guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html For example, instead of `if (!$code)`, write `if ( ! $code)`. In my opinion, codeigniter's style guide is my favorite for php.

Comment: Your code makes no sence, if( ! $code ) validate else grab user  ?  Your naming convention is also a little muddled, code = id .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
```

is redundant, just use...

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

---

Also, you can move the whole `if (empty($user_id))` block outside to the end to avoid duplicating it:

```
$code = $this->uri->segment(3);

if (!$code) {
    // validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'PassCode',
        'required|trim|max_length[100]|xss_clean');

    // run validation to check if validation rules are satifised
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $user_id = $this->user_model->getUserId($code);
    }
} else {
    $user_id = $this->user_model->getUserId($code);
}

if (empty($user_id)) {
    $data['errorMessage'] = 'Your code is not valid.';
} else {
    redirect('user/profile');   
}
```